# how to pass in multiple values into a template to run a query

Tags: postgresql, templates, go

Options 
I have web app with a search bar. The search bar accepts customer_id's and runs a query to a redshift cluster with the customer_id as a filter. I need to be able to input multiple customer id's comma separated and then run the query filtered by those customer id's. Currently i can only use 1 customer id at a time. Here is what i currently use. Any help or guidance is appreciated.

```
func riiapp(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

oname := r.PostFormValue("orderid")

rows, err := db.Query("SELECT rma_id, order_id, customer_id, bin_id, owner, asin, lpn, warehouse_id FROM crt.returns_in_inv WHERE (warehouse_id IN ($1) OR lower(warehouse_id) IN ($1)) OR lpn IN ($1) OR asin IN ($1) OR rma_id IN ($1) OR customer_id IN ($1) OR ORDER_ID IN ($1);", oname)
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, http.StatusText(500), 500)
    return
}
defer rows.Close()

bks := make([]Book, 0)
for rows.Next() {
    bk := Book{}
    err := rows.Scan(&bk.Rmaid, &bk.Orderid, &bk.Customerid, &bk.Binid, &bk.Owner, &bk.Asin, &bk.Lpn, &bk.Warehouseid) // order matters
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(500), 500)
        return
    }
    bks = append(bks, bk)
}
if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
    http.Error(w, http.StatusText(500), 500)
    return
}

tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "riiapp.gohtml", bks)
fmt.Println(oname)
}

<html>
<div class="container" align="center">
<h6>Search By: Rma_Id, Order Id, Customer ID, Asin, LPN OR Warehouse ID (May Pull Many Records)</h6>
<form action="/riiapp" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="orderid" id="ord" placeholder="SEARCH">
<input type="submit">
</form>




<table id="testTable">
  <thead valign="top">
    <tr>         
        <th>Rma_id</th>
        <th>Order_id</th>
        <th>Customer_id</th>
        <th>Bin_id</th>
        <th>Owner</th>
        <th>Asin</th>
        <th>Lpn</th>
        <th>Warehouse_id</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>{{range .}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{.Rmaid}}</td>
        <td>{{.Orderid}}</td>
        <td>{{.Customerid}}</td>
        <td>{{.Binid}}</td>
        <td>{{.Owner}}</td>
        <td>{{.Asin}}</td>
        <td>{{.Lpn}}</td>
        <td>{{.Warehouseid}}</td>
    </tr>
        {{end}}
  </tbody>
</table>
 </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two options, building a string of placeholders and interpolating them into the query before passing the parameters, or instead of using `IN` you switch to using `ANY` together with [`lib/pq.Int64Array`](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#Int64Array).

Building your own placeholders:

```
orderid := "44,33,55,66" // get input

ids := strings.Split(orderid, ",")
if len(ids) < 1 {
    return // exit if no input
}

placeholders := ""
for i := range ids {
    placeholders += ",$" + strconv.Itoa(i+1)
}
placeholders = placeholders[1:] // remove leading comma

query := `SELECT
    rma_id,
    order_id,
    customer_id,
    bin_id,
    owner,
    asin,
    lpn,
    warehouse_id
FROM crt.returns_in_inv
WHERE (warehouse_id IN (%[1]s) OR lower(warehouse_id) IN (%[1]s))
OR lpn IN (%[1]s)
OR asin IN (%[1]s)
OR rma_id IN (%[1]s)
OR customer_id IN (%[1]s)
OR ORDER_ID IN (%[1]s);`

query = fmt.Sprintf(query, placeholders) // inject placeholders $1,$2,$3,$4 into query template
rows, err := db.Query(query, ids...) // execute query
// ...
```

---

Using `ANY`:

```
orderid := "44,33,55,66" // get input

ids := strings.Split(orderid, ",")
if len(ids) < 1 {
    return // exit if no input
}

params := make(pq.Int64Array, len(ids))
for i, s := range ids {
    id, err := strconv.ParseInt(s, 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return // fail
    }
    params[i] = id
}

query := `SELECT
    rma_id,
    order_id,
    customer_id,
    bin_id,
    owner,
    asin,
    lpn,
    warehouse_id
FROM crt.returns_in_inv
WHERE (warehouse_id = ANY ($1) OR lower(warehouse_id) = ANY ($1))
OR lpn = ANY ($1)
OR asin = ANY ($1)
OR rma_id = ANY ($1)
OR customer_id = ANY ($1)
OR ORDER_ID IN = ANY ($1)`

rows, err := db.Query(query, params)
// ...
```

Comment: I used the first section cause i'm searching for strings and numbers in my query. It works amazing and you are the most awesome person ever!!. I did have to add 1 thing to it and i got it to work. I'll post it below.

Answer (score 0):

```
//This is the code that i got to work. Thank you so much @mkopriva !!!
//You are freaking awesome!! I did have to add in 1 thing to it.

func riiapp(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

oname := r.PostFormValue("orderid")

ids := strings.Split(oname, ",")
if len(ids) < 1 {
    return // exit if no input
}

placeholders := ""
for i := range ids {
    placeholders += ",$" + strconv.Itoa(i+1)
}
placeholders = placeholders[1:] // remove leading comma

t := ids
s := make([]interface{}, len(t))
for i, v := range t {
    s[i] = v
}

query := `SELECT
rma_id,
order_id,
customer_id,
bin_id,
owner,
asin,
lpn,
warehouse_id
FROM z_support.returns_in_inv
WHERE (warehouse_id IN (%[1]s) OR lower(warehouse_id) IN (%[1]s))
OR lpn IN (%[1]s)
OR asin IN (%[1]s)
OR rma_id IN (%[1]s)
OR customer_id IN (%[1]s)
OR ORDER_ID IN (%[1]s);`

query = fmt.Sprintf(query, placeholders) // inject placeholders $1,$2,$3,$4 into 
query template
rows, err := db.Query(query, s...)       // execute query
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return
}
defer rows.Close()

bks := make([]Book, 0)
for rows.Next() {
    bk := Book{}
    err := rows.Scan(&bk.Rmaid, &bk.Orderid, &bk.Customerid, &bk.Binid, &bk.Owner, 
&bk.Asin, &bk.Lpn, &bk.Warehouseid) // order matters
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(500), 500)
        return
    }
    bks = append(bks, bk)
}
if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
    http.Error(w, http.StatusText(500), 500)
    return
}

tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "riiapp.gohtml", bks)

}
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)

Comment: Buddy, i barely understand the code myself. How do you expect me to explain it to you?

Comment: Oh, is this an answer? You're saying "Thank you so much @mkopriva" so this is a comment, right?